# Algorithm to find least sum of squares of differences

Tags: python, algorithm

Basically this algorithm I'm writing takes as input a List L and wants to find a number x such that all items in L, i,  minus x  squared and summed are minimized.  Find minimum x for the sum of `abs(L[i]-x)**2`.  So far my algorithm is doing what it's supposed to, just not in the cases of floating.  I'm not sure how to implement floating.  For example `[2, 2, 3, 4]` ideally would yield the result `2.75`, but my algorithm isn't currently capable of yielding floating integers.

```
 def minimize_square(L):
     sumsqdiff = 0
     sumsqdiffs = {}
     for j in range(min(L), max(L)):
             for i in range(len(L)-1):
                     sumsqdiff += abs(L[i]-j)**2
             sumsqdiffs[j]=sumsqdiff
             sumsqdiff = 0
     return min(sumsqdiffs, key=sumsqdiffs.get)
```

Comment: You can create a float from a number by using `float(number)`. Any further operation involving `number` will then give a floating-point result.

Comment: Are you more interested in finding the value, or understanding and improving your algorithm as a programming exercise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is easy to prove [*] that the number that minimizes the sum of squared differences is the arithmetic [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) of `L`. This gives the following simple solution:

```
In [26]: L = [2, 2, 3, 4]

In [27]: sum(L) / float(len(L))
Out[27]: 2.75
```

or, using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/):

```
In [28]: numpy.mean(L)
Out[28]: 2.75
```

[*] Here is an outline of the proof:

We need to find `x` that minimizes `f(x) = sum((x - L[i])**2)` where the sum is taken over `i=0..n-1`.

Take the derivative of `f(x)` and [set it to zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)):

```
2*sum(x - L[i]) = 0
```

Using simple algebra, the above can be transformed into

```
x = sum(L[i]) / n
```

which is none other than the arithmetic mean of `L`. QED.

Comment: +1. Can you add a short proof or link to one? I'm very interested. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's necessarily true though.  Here are some tests with random numbers to show:                                                                            >>> L = [random.randrange(100) for i in range(20)]
>>> avgL = sum(L)/len(L)
>>> avgL
58
>>> minimize_square(L)
59
>>> L = [random.randrange(100) for i in range(20)]
>>> avgL = sum(L)/len(L)
>>> avgL
51
>>> minimize_square(L)
49
>>> L = [random.randrange(100) for i in range(20)]
>>> avgL = sum(L)/len(L)
>>> avgL
53
>>> minimize_square(L)
55
>>>

Comment: @rubik: I've added an outline of the proof.

Comment: @madman2890, your >>> L = [random.randrange(100) for i in range(20)] >>> avgL = sum(L)/len(L) >>> avgL 51 >>> minimize_square(L) 49 computation is defective because you didn't float(len(L)).  Ie you computed with avgL being integer truncation of average, but not equal to the average

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate the feedback it helps when you're just learning this stuff, especially from @NPE

Comment: I never completely understood why in Ordinary Least Squares regression of form y = beta_0 + e, beta_0 is just a mean of y. Now everything connected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I actually just read an exhaustive algebraic approach instead of the derivative approach.  Same conclusion.

Comment: @Akavall: Funnily enough, it's mainly because of OLS that I instantly thought of the mean when I read the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this is the most efficient way to do this but what you could do is mantain the same algorithm that you have and modify the return statement.

```
min_int = min(sumsqdiffs, key=sumsqdiffs.get)
return bisection(L,min_int-1,min_int+1)
```

where `bisection` implement the following method: [Bisection Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)

This works iff there is a single minimum for the function in the analyzed interval.

Comment: Did not think that it was a sum of squared differences -> look at @NPE answer.